# Problem visualizing this vector field.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, vector-fields

Let $F(x, y) = x\hat{i} - y\hat{j}$, then the magnitude is $$|F| = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}.$$

I know that when both $x$ and $y$ have the same value the magnitude is $0$.

Is there any algorithm to visualize vector fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the magnitude of your vector field is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, not $\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$.

(Indeed, given a vector $V = (v_1,...,v_n)$, its standard Euclidean norm is $|V| = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2$).

---

Now, your vector field is $F(x,y) = x\hat{i} - y\hat{j}$. In vector notation, $F(x,y) = \displaystyle\binom{x}{-y}$.

This means that to every point $(x,y)$ in the plane, you are assigning the vector $\displaystyle\binom{x}{-y}$. So to visualize it, just draw a plane, pick a couple of points (you could pick the grid points for example), and draw the associated vectors. Given a large enough number of points, this will give you a good visualization of what the vector field looks like, and is easy to do by hand.

---

Of course, you could decide to do that informatically if you want to. Some versions already exist and are easy to come by if you look for vector field visualizers.

[Here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/QPE4PaDZ) is one on geogebra for example.

Comment: can you give me some examples of points

Comment: and how do you know where the arrow points

Comment: Ok, let us take a few examples. Our vector field associates the vector $(x, -y)$ to the point $(x,y)$. (I'm writing the vectors horizontally because of the comment format). So for example, to the point $(1,0$, you'd associate the vector $(1,0)$ (which goes one to the right horizontally). To the point $(1,1)$, you'd associate the vector $(1, -1)$, which goes one to the right, one down. And to the point $(0,1)$, you'd associate the vector $(0, -1)$. Here is what it would look like: https://ibb.co/4gtmQm5

Comment: Now, of course, you'd need to draw a few more to get the hang of what the vector field looks like. But after computing a few points, you start getting a feel of how it looks like. I drew a few more here: https://ibb.co/hVZkdbz (sizes may not be perfectly to scale). The best way to get a hang of it is to just do a few examples: pick a vector field, try drawing it on paper, then check against an online tool like geogebra to see if you got it right!

Comment: It doesn't point towards the origin, where did you see that? $F(2, -2) = (2, 2)$, so it should point "northeast" from the point $(2, -2)$

Comment: got it thanks...

Answer (score 1):

First off, the magnitude is $$|F| = \sqrt{|x|^2 + |-y|^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$ This has magnitude $0$ only at the origin and the magnitude is equal to the distance from the origin.

Vector fields can be plotted in many ways and there are a lot of resources available online. The most popular way of visualizing vector fields is a quiver plot. See [this Geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/QPE4PaDZ) for an example. Here is a plot of this vector field in a square about the origin.[image]

A plot like this could be approximated by hand by simply picking some points in the plane, computing the vector field, then drawing an arrow starting at your selected point in the direction of the vector field. Quiver plots also usually scale the length or weight of the drawn arrows by the magnitude of the vector field.

Comment: @whpowelll Is there any way to sketch by hand?